# ios-13-App crashes when setting UIColor as BackgroundImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uisearchbar

I am trying to set `searchbar` background image with `UIColor`. My code is working fine in ios 12.x but It is crashing in ios 13. My code is as follows.

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setScopeBarBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([UIColor clearColor])]];
```

The crash log says **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'imageRef passed is not a CGImageRef'**

Can anyone suggest alternative way to resolve crash?

Comment: Surprising that didn't give you trouble prior to iOS 13... This: `(__bridge CGImageRef)([UIColor clearColor])` does *not* return a `CGImage` / `CGImageRef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're casting a UIColor object to a CGImageRef. This doesn't make sense, and I don't know why it would have worked in iOS 12.

You probably want to just make a UIImage filled with a solid color. Something like this:
https://gist.github.com/uknowho/5915365